# C# store confidential information

Tags: c#, xml, sqlite

I get stack... I would like to save data from c# application either to XML or sqllite but since this is confidential information I don't want it to be accesible directly ... only from my password secured app. What type of datastore is better to use and how to secure them? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

a. protect the data store it self - physically, and with access permission

b. protect the data itself - encrypt it with a key and either really guard that key, or don't write it anywhere, unless you accessing the data (but then you need to type the key each time, store it in memory, and dispose it later).

there is a lot to learn and more solutions to use - but I need more information about your app, your environment, the "Attack" surface ect...

Comment: I am moving my excel app to c# winform, until now it is protected only with password wich user must enter at the beginning. What I am trying to achieve is that my database since it will be separate file won't be accessed directly.

Answer (score 0):

Either data store is vulnerable - if you want to protect the data, you need to encrypt it.

This, of course, only scratches at the surface of [information security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security).

There are many aspects you need to think about and provide for:

- Storing the password/key
- Access to the datastore
- Access to the data stored in the datastore

And more...

Answer (score 0):

You have to encrypt data and put them in database or xml. At that point if someone get your database or xml it is useful because data in there is not usable. Maybe you can use Public-key cryptography. With public key encrypt data and put it in database, and with private key you are able to get plain text. It all depends on purpose of your program.